# Unable to skip the destruction of ECR repo of Terraform resources

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I am trying to run in a Github Action pipeline a simple workflow where, given a working infrastructure composed of multiple AWS resources, I want to shutdown and destroy all of it, except one element (the ECR cluster).

The infra is written in Terraform and it is composed of multiple files. One of these resources is an ECR cluster, which it usually has several images on it.
When I run the Github workflow, the destroy step gets an error saying that the cluster cannot be destroyed because it is not empty.

```
╷
│ Error: ECR Repository (container-test) not empty, consider using force_delete: RepositoryNotEmptyException: The repository with name 'container-test' in registry with id '264416219674' cannot be deleted because it still contains images
│ 
│ 
╵
Error: Terraform exited with code 1.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Any idea how could I skip this error/element? The pipeline indeed is working, because it is removing everything but the cluster, but still it is marked as an error.
I have tried using the "prevent-destroy" component in the ECR, but no luck. As well, I can't build two different terraform runs and execute two when I want to build the infra but only destroy one, because the resources are coupled between them.

May thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use for force_delete to protect repos that have data:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "foo" {
  name                 = "bar"
  image_tag_mutability = "MUTABLE"
  force_delete = false
}
```

If you don't want empty repos to be deleted, my advice is that create a separate infrastructure component for it. Storage resources like ECR, S3, Backups, EFS, FSx, RDS, ... all need to be treated with care to prevent data loss.

Comment: Using `force_delete` does not prevent to see the error and the fail of the pipeline. I agree it would be good to create another infra component for store resources, but since it's an easy project and my resource is quite coupled to the rest, I was looking for something easier.

Comment: you can remove it from the state before destroying and then import it again.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but this will require a manual action (removing from the state), and I am executing a pipeline. Or is it possible to remove from the terraform state programatically?

Comment: You can do it from terraform by using a destroy provisioner on aws_ecr_repository

```provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command
}``` see https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#destroy-time-provisioners

Comment: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/rm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @victor I managed to do the trick.
I had to first remove from the state the resources I didn't want to remove, then destroy the rest of resources and eventually import again the resources previously removed.
So for anyone interested, my final Github Action pipeline jobs looks like that:

```
jobs:
  terraform:
    name: "Terraform Infrastructure Destroy Infraestructure"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: write-all
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repository to the runner
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Terraform with specified version on the runner
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.5.0
      
      - name: Terraform init
        id: init
        run: terraform init

      - name: Remove from state resources to not destroy
        id: rmstate
        run: |
          terraform state rm aws_ecr_repository.container_test
          terraform state rm aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket

      - name: Terraform Destroy
        id: destroy
        run: terraform destroy -auto-approve
      
      - name: Import to state resources not destroyed
        id: import
        run: |
          terraform import aws_ecr_repository.container_test container-test
          terraform import aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket test-bucket-name-remove
```

It's a pity that terraform does not provide any param or mechanism to destroy all resources except one or some of them, while it offers a param to destroy a selected target. Otherwise we wouldn't need to do all these steps.